# Downloading a large number of small files from Google Drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I have a folder in Google Drive that is shared to public and it has thousands of files in the size range 5-8 MBs each.

I tried the following to download each file at a time:

Get a list of file IDs/names from the folder using getfilelistpy package as follows:

```
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist

resource = {
    "api_key": API_KEY,
    "id": FOLDER_ID,
    "fields": "files(name,id)",
}
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
print(res)
```

Once the file list is obtained I am looping through each file and use wget to download the file as follows:

```
for i in range(Len(id_list)):
    command1 = "wget --no-check-certificate -r 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id={}' -O '{}'".format(id_list[i], file_name_list[i])
    os.system(command1)
```

After 65-66 files, the file size download is 0 KB. Does Google Drive put a limit on the number of files/file size one can download? How can we over come that?

Any help would be appreciated? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried resuming the program from whichever file it breaks at? (file 65/66 in your case)

Comment: Yes. If I resume it immediately, it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the file size where it breaks? Also, are there access right issues?

Comment: Around 7 MB. No access right issues. The same files gets downloaded after a few hours.

Comment: From your script, I thought that those files might have been publicly shared. If my understanding is correct, when the files are downloaded using API key, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike Not sure if I understand you question. Yes the files are publicly shared.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could know that the files you want to download have been publicly shared. From this situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, the API key is used. In this case, it is considered that the files in the folder are publicly shared. From your replying, also it was found that the files have been publicly shared. So in this answer, I would like to propose to download the files using the API key.

The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
import requests
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist

API_KEY = '###'  # Please set your API key.
FOLDER_ID = '###'  # Please set the folder ID.

resource = {
    "api_key": API_KEY,
    "id": FOLDER_ID,
    "fields": 'nextPageToken, files(id,name,webContentLink,mimeType)',
}
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
for files in res['fileList']:
    for file in files['files']:
        if 'google' not in file['mimeType']:
            filename = file['name']
            print('%s is downloading.' % filename)
            r = requests.get(file['webContentLink'], stream=True)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(r.content)
```

#### Reference:

- [getfilelistpy](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy)